# Understanding bind() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma

As per MDN:  [The bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method)

> Calling `f.bind(someObject)` creates a new function with the same body
>   and scope as `f`, but where this occurs in the original function, in the
>   new function it is permanently bound to the first argument of `bind`,
>   regardless of how the function is being used:

```
function f() {
  return this.a;
}

var g = f.bind({a: 'azerty'});
console.log(g()); // azerty

var h = g.bind({a: 'yoo'}); // bind only works once!
console.log(h()); // azerty

var o = {a: 37, f: f, g: g, h: h};
console.log(o.a, o.f(), o.g(), o.h()); // 37, 37, azerty, azerty
```

But when I try the code below:

```js
var module = {
  x: 42,
  getX: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
}
    
var unboundGetX = module.getX;
console.log(unboundGetX()); // The function gets invoked at the global scope
// expected output: undefined
    
var boundGetX = unboundGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX()); // expected output: 42
 
module.x = 43;
boundGetY = boundGetX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetY()); // shouldn't this be 42??
```

**Expected output:**

```
undefined
42
42
```

**Actual output:**

```
undefined
42
43
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: After the `module.x = 43;` line runs, `module.x` is 43, not 42, thus you see 43? There's no 42 in memory anywhere after that point, why would you expect to see 42?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Because they say `bind()` is permanent and works only once with the first parameter passed to it?

Comment: No, it doesn't only work once, you can continue calling the bound function as many times as you like, and `.bind` doesn't deep clone the new `this` or anything like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here module is a constant, but module.x is not. that's the reason you can change module.x value but you can't change module.

so you are changing value of module, not module itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following what you are confused about - it looks like it is working as described.

1. unboundGetX is a reference to your function.
2. You change the value of `module.x` to 43
3. You create a new method `boundGetY` by calling `unboundGetX.bind(module)` - ie, the `this` that boundGetY refers to is `module`.
4. You call `boundGetY()` - it refers to `this.x` which is the value of the `module.x`, 43.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value of the same object then you are not binding another object so the value is changed.

```js
  var module = {
      x: 42,
      getX: function() {
        return this.x;
      }
    }
    
    var unboundGetX = module.getX;
    console.log(unboundGetX()); // The function gets invoked at the global scope
    // expected output: undefined
    
    var boundGetX = unboundGetX.bind(module);
    console.log(boundGetX());  // expected output: 42
   
    var module2 = {
      x: 43,
      getX: function() {
        return this.x;
      }
    }
    boundGetY = boundGetX.bind(module);
    console.log(boundGetY());
```